# Why is the ListBoxItem content indented to the left?

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, listboxitem, itemtemplate

I am sure this is something only my newb-ness can create, but, as seen in the screenshot, the border specified in the code snippet renders slightly indented from the left:

[image]

Here is the code for the data template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="itemsTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayString}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Cursor="Hand" FontFamily="Tahoma" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I added the border on the left to better illustrate the problem. What I really want is the bottom border to extend the full width of the ListboxItem.  Why is it indented?  How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to DataTemplate you should declare this Style:

```
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="0"/>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that it is the ListBox that is doing that--setting a margin on the container for the listbox item.  probably you are going to have to set a margin on your border that is like, -5 (or so) to get it back over where you want it.

something like this:

```
<Border margin="-5,0,0,0">.....</Border>
```

should fix it